# Dynamic addition of queues to a rabbit listener at runtime

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I've got a project where we are going to have hundreds (potentially thousands) of queues in rabbit and each of these queues will need to be consumed by a pool of consumers.

In rabbit (using spring-amqp), you have the rabbitlistener annotation which allows me to statically assign the queues this particular consumer(s) will handle.

My question is - with rabbit and spring, is there a clean way for me to grab a section of queues (lets say queues that start with a-c) and then also listen for any queues that are created while the consumer is running.

Example (at start):

- ant-queue
- apple-queue
- cat-queue

While consumer is running:

- Add bat-queue

Here is the (very simple) code I currently have:

```
    @Component
    public class MessageConsumer {

        public MessageConsumer() {
            // ideally grab a section of queues here, initialize a parameter and give to the rabbitlistener annotation
        }

        @RabbitListener(queues= {"ant-queue", "apple-queue", "cat-queue"})
        public void processQueues(String messageAsJson) {
            < how do I update the queues declared in rabbit listener above ? >
        }
    }
```

Edit:

I should add - I've gone through the spring amqp documentation I found online and I haven't found anything outside of statically (either hardcoded or via properties) declaring the queues

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Inject (`@Autowired` or otherwise) the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`.
- Get a reference to the listener container (use the `id` attribute on the annotation to give it a known id) (`registry.getListenerContainer(id)`).
- Cast the container to an `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` and call `addQueues()` or `addQueueNames()`.

Note that is more efficient to use a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` when adding queues dynamically; with a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` the consumer(s) are stopped and restarted. With the direct container, each queue gets its own consumer(s).

See [Choosing a container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#choose-container).

Comment: "With the direct container, each queue gets its own consumer(s)" - music to my ears. Thank you for the info!

Comment: Gary - my mistake. Is it possible to asynchronously determine queues that exist within a rabbitmq server based on a certain naming convention? In theory, we would need to poll every second to determine which queues exist and create a consumer for it.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments to old answers, it won't help other people when searching for answers; ask a new question instead. There is nothing in the AMQP protocol to do that; RabbitMQ does provide a REST API (and a [java binding for it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#management-rest-api)), but I would suggest that polling (especially at that rate) would not be a good idea. Consider adding a consumer for a queue bound to the [event exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html) instead; you can get `queue.created` events.

Comment: Thanks Gary - apologies for the question in comment

Comment: @GaryRussell could you please share any example of this. It is exactly what we are looking for, however we want a hybrid approach where some queue names are known in advance and some new queues will be discovered at runtime.

Comment: It is better to ask a new question showing your config so I can understand how you are using the framework to give you the best answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @GaryRussell. I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63162812/rabbitmq-dynamic-addition-of-queues-to-a-listener-at-runtime

Comment: @GaryRussell registry.getListenerContainer(id) and adding a queue name to it takes a long time, and I'm adding queue names in the container from another rabbitlistener. Isn't there a faster approach or any other way to make it faster?

Comment: It's best to ask a new question, with much more information, rather than commenting on a 3 year old answer. That said, using a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` will probably be quite a bit faster; aside from that, I am not aware of any issues.

Comment: Is there an example of an implementation of this reply?

Comment: Which reply? Why don't you ask a new question with more clarity; I can then add an answer with an example if needed. The admins here don't like prolonged discussions in comments on old answers.